# TableView / CellValueFactory - Change displayed property based on value of another property

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a `TableView` populated with a custom object; the table displays the properties of that object.

My question is how can I bind a different property to the column based on the value of another property for that row?

For example, suppose I have this object:

```
public class MyObject() {
    private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleStringProperty type = new SimpleStringProperty("");
}
```

Now in the `TableView`, I have the two columns:

```
+---------+--------+
| NAME    | TYPE   |
+---------+--------+
| Robert  | Mgr    |
+---------+--------+
```

However, if `type = "Something"`, I want the `Type` column to actually display the value of the `name` property instead:

```
+---------+--------+
| NAME    | TYPE   |
+---------+--------+
| Robert  | Robert |
+---------+--------+
```

I am unclear how to go about setting a different `PropertyValueFactory` based on the value of another property within the same object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

Edit to show column definition - this needs to take the object as a whole, not a string.

```
@FXML 
private TableColumn<MyObject,MyObject> changingColumn;
```

...

```
//Where you initialize the table
changingColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(cellData.getValue()));
changingColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<MyObject, MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(MyObject item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText("");
            } else if ("something".equals(item.getType())){
                setText(item.getName());
            }else {
                setText(item.getType());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I am having trouble trying to adapt this to my own situation. First of all, `new TableCell<MyObject, MyObject>()` throws a "Bad return type in lambda" error as the second argument is expecting a `String`, not an object.

Comment: I have updated to show how to define your column - it should take the object, not a string.

Comment: Thank you. That worked out well too. I actually just solved the issue as well, using just a `CellValueFactory` with a Lamba expression. I've added my answer below as well as it seems to be just a little simpler.

Comment: I have done it both ways - really depends on what you are needing.  I like the cell factory - as it provides more flexibility in the long run.  You may have different data types, or a different object, or something you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the following solution as well:

```
colType.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            if (param.getValue() != null) {
                if (param.getValue().getType().equals("Something")) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getName);
                } else {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getType());
                }
            } else {
                return new SimpleStringProperty("");
            }
        });
```